# Is Qt framework similar to Titanium?

Tags: iphone, android, qt, titanium

I came to  know that Qt framework can let us develop Applications for [Android and iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework)). Have some ever developed applications and submitted the Apps in App store and Android market. Is it similar to Titanium in the way of using same source code base for different platforms. If that is the case, can we use the same code for Nokia Applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone thing you're mentioning is a wrapper around cocoa, but it's important to note that it's nothing official, it's more like a 'hobby hack'. Same with the android port. These projects are incomplete with no scheduled release date, so I wouldn't count on them if I were you.

But yeah, the way they are worded it seems like they are just wrapping around the platform specific code, so one should be able to use the same code, if these ports were complete that is.